# Static methods in R6 classes

Tags: r, r6

Is there a way to add static methods to R6 classes? For example, a function that can be called like

```
MyClass$method()
```

Instead of

```
myinstance <- MyClass$new()
myinstance$method()
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not an expert on R6 but since every R6 class is an environment, you can add anything you want to this environment.

Like:

```
MyClass$my_static_method <- function(x) { x + 2}
MyClass$my_static_method(1)
#[1] 3
```

But the method will **not work on the instance of the class**:

```
instance1 <- MyClass$new()
instance1$my_static_method(1)
# Error: attempt to apply non-function
```

You should be careful with the existing objects in the class environment. To see what is already defined use `ls(MyClass)`

Comment: See also [github.com/r-lib/R6#66  : Consider adding static methods/fields (issue open)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28916460/static-methods-in-r6-classes)

Answer (score 1):

I have used a workaround for the solution. You can access the methods without creating the instance by calling `MyClass$public_methods$my_static_method()`. 
To restrict the calls without the instance, I have made `self` as an argument in all of the methods.

Comment: So you made every instance method and every call to an instance method more complex by adding a redundant argument? Doesn't that kind of beat the purpose of the whole R6 class system? The developers of R6 invested a lot of time and ingenuity to make sure that the instance methods get their context without needing a 'self' argument.